# c# after client runs my program the excel sheet the program writes always opens when excel is opened

Tags: c#, excel, com

I have created a C# program that takes a XML document as input, drag and drop on exe.  The output is an xlsx sheet i create using the input.
When I give the exe to a coworker to run, it works as expected, and outputs the xlsx.  But now after the coworker closes out of excel and opens any excel workbook any where on the computer, the xlsx that was created from my program always opens.
This doesn't happen on my computer.  Not sure how it's even possible.  Is there some setting I am missing in saving the files?

```
public static void WriteFile2(string filePath, InitialData initialData)
    {
        var excelApp = new Application {Visible = false};

        var workbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
        _Workbook workbook = workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        var sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
        var worksheet = (_Worksheet) sheets.Item[1];
        worksheet.Name = "BGPM1000XX";
        excelApp.StandardFont = "Arial";
        excelApp.StandardFontSize = 8;
/*Skipping body of code, mostly writing to cells and formatting*/
        //Insert Cover sheet tab

        var newWorksheet = (Worksheet) excelApp.Worksheets.Add();

        newWorksheet.Name = "COVER SHEET";
/*Skipping body of code, mostly writing to cells and formatting*/


        try
        {
            //TODO: make png path generic
#if DEBUG
             var fileName = @"..\..\..\ExternalReferences\logo.png";
            var newname = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);

           newWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(
                newname,

                MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 280, 5, 55, 45);
#else

            newWorksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(
               @"logo.png",

               MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 280, 5, 55, 45);
#endif
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }


        workbook.Saved = true;
        var version = 1;
        var inUse = true;
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        while (inUse)
        {
            inUse = IsFileInUse(filePath);
            if (!inUse)
                break;
            filePath = filePath.Substring(0, filePath.Length - extension.Length) + "_V" + version + ".xlsx";
            version++;
        }
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        //workbook.SaveAs(filePath);
        workbook.SaveAs(filePath, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        excelApp.UserControl = false;
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you kill the process if there is an exception in your code. A good way to handle it is with a try..catch block. After you call the exception, call something like this:

```
public void KillProcess()
{
    _workBook.Close();
    _workBooks.Close();
    _excelApp.Quit();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_workSheets);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_workBook);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_workBooks);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_excelApp);
}
```

Also, to clean up all of your previous EXCEL tasks, restart your computer.

Comment: this works.  I didn't realize in my own Task Manager I had so many Excel processes hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1. Put in a call to `Close` the document before you call `Quit`.
2. Place the whole Excel code into a try catch and have this command as a finally to release the com object.

   `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject( excelApp );`

I base this advice off of my blog article [C# Open Word Documents using Visual Studio 2010 and .Net 4](http://omegacoder.com/?p=555) which provides an example of working with the interops.

Comment: this would probably also work, but I saw sapbuckets post and it works.  thanks